# Why is there a Level 40 in my ~Level 20 match?

Tags: tribes-ascend

I was playing Tribes: Ascend on the public servers, which are only for people of a certain rank boundary, however I saw by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> that there was a Level 40 on the enemy team.  This is twice the average level of the players.

Why is this happening?  I though the matches were limited by level to stop this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way `Tribes: Ascend` works is by having separate servers for each level boundary, and you will join one of those.  However, if someone (E.g. that Level 40) was friends with a level 20.  They could use the "Join Match" button via the friends list and end up in an easy match.

I'm not sure what Hi-Rez are doing on the matter.  They could limit the levels when joining friends, but this would stop friends of different levels playing together as likely all your friends are not the same level as you.

Comment: Don't like playing against the lower levels? What happens if a guy like me(level 17) is just as good or better than my level 40 friends. I think that is fair that I be able to play with the better competition.

Comment: Well that in my opinion should be fine.  It's the high levels invading on the lower levels for XP profit that I have a problem with.

Comment: I agree with you there man.  If i'm against bad players I usually just work on my routes or practice other classes

Answer (score 2):

The matchmaking system *attempts* to put people in games with other players of similar rank, but it's not always possible to do so. Perhaps yours was the only game available when that person joined the queue. (Historical note: Until a recent patch, there were only two pools of games: One for players rank 7 and below, and another for *everyone else*.)

The other possibility is that the person was playing with a friend. You can *always* join a friend's game, regardless of what level either of you are. However, since rank is a measure of *time played* (XP earned) and not a direct measure of skill, this isn't as big a deal as it seems.